# How to avoid bias/avoid overfitting when choosing a machine learning model?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff, bias-correction

My typical workflow in the past, when creating machine learning models, has been to do the following:

1. Decide on some candidate model families for the task at hand.
2. Divide dataset into train and test sets. Set aside the test set, and pretend it doesn't exist.
3. Do some EDA on the training set.
4. For each model candidate, (depending on the results of the EDA), tune hyperparameters and estimate generalization error via nested cross validation.
5. Choose whichever model family has the best performance in step 4.
6. Check performance of the model chosen from step 5 on the holdout test set.

I feel like this still introduces bias. In step 5, we're picking a model family based on performance in the nested cross validation. Is this safe to do?

Also, how do we decide on the hyperparameters to try? I feel like one's choice is to get an idea for the ideal range and then do a grid search, or else do a wide grid search over hyperparameters which might leave some performance on the table.

Finally, how do you actually choose a final model?

Comment: There is a possible step between 5 and 6, which is once you have your selected model family and tuned its hyperparameters, you can retrain on the full training set.

Comment: The cross-validation step 4 is there to reduce excess overfitting, including choosing hyperparmeters which tend to achieve this.  It cannot eliminate the risk, and the testing step 6 is designed to indicate how well you turn out to have done.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are doing EDA then you will get to know about if there is a bias or not from data side. On the other hand, if you ask me about the model being biased then I can say that if you can reduce the overfitting then it's highly likely that you will reduce some of the bias. Or you can choose another model to train.
- Second, if you think that nested cross validation is introducing some bias, then you can try with other cross validation techniques. But cross validation techniques are there to deal with these cases.
- Third, about which hyperparameters to tune, there is a framework called optuna: https://optuna.org/. It uses random search over the range of parameters. Now why I am suggesting you is because it can plot the hyperparameters that are actually influencing the model. So you can see the hyperparameters that are actually useful to tune. So do check it out.
- Lastly, choosing a final model could be tricky. Why? Because different domains have different use cases. For e.g. banking, domain needs the models that can be explained easily. Other domain might require you to create a model that gives the metric score as good as possible. So, it depends on your domain and use case. But in general case, you need model to be less biased, highly explainable (except you are using black box model like Neural Network). RandomForest is a good start as it has low bias and low variance.
  Hope I answered your questions.